# What exactly does "probable open proxy: command=POST" mean in sendmail logs?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I noticed the following in my sendmail logs:

```
May 11 11:11:16 foobox sendmail[21111]: uADEFHG21111: [1.1.1.1]: probable open proxy: command=POST http://foo2.example.com
May 11 11:11:16 foobox sendmail[21111]: uADEFHG21111: [1.1.1.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

(IPs, QIDs, and dates changed to protect the innocent :-))

Here's another few errors:

```
May 11 12:12:12 foobox sendmail[22222]: u4BACDCDC22222: [1.1.1.1]: probable open proxy: command=GET http://example2.domain.com/foo2/
May 11 12:12:12 foobox sendmail[22222]: u4BACDCDC22222: [1.1.1.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

I haven't seen this before and it's unclear to me what exactly is happening here.  Can someone elaborate? Something is attempting to initiate a SMTP connection through a web connection? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail assumes that it is "very likely" that the connection came through an open http proxy.
It would be "unwise" from spam prevention perspective to send standard "unrecognized command" reply and accept next SMTP commands. [It is implemented in `srvrsmtp.c`]

HTTP proxy server may send/relay valid SMTP commands embedded into HTTP request.  Without this improvement it could lead to accepting email messages especially to local mailboxes.

IMHO it is less useful that it had used to be **BUT** it still remains far away from being removed from sendmail's code.

sendmail's [`RELEASE_NOTES`](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/older_release_notes/) file:

```
8.14.0/8.14.0   2007/01/31  
  ....
  Try to deal with open HTTP proxies that are used to send spam
    by recognizing some commands from them. If the first command
    from the client is GET, POST, CONNECT, or USER, then the
    connection is terminated immediately.
```

Comment: Sorry.. I'm still struggling to understand... `post` and `get` aren't valid SMTP commands right? So why would the remote proxy even be trying to use them?

Comment: Remote http proxy treats sendmail as www server. Initial **relayed** HTTP command gives it away.  It is not "intended use". it is abuse prevented at sendmail stage.

Comment: I see.  So even though the remote proxy is connecting on TCP/25, it immediately begins issuing non-SMTP commands... and at best, that wastes time/resources so sendmail immediately terminates the connection?  Is this a configurable feature?  Or just something that's permanently added? I don't see a reason to allow this but am curious if the behavior is hard-coded or not.

Comment: It seems to be hardcoded in  `sedmail/srvrsmtp.c` WITH no config-file option and no compile time option to turn it off. [impression based on sendmail-8.15.1 sources]

Comment: BTW after an initial http command the proxy may send/relay valid SMTP commands embedded into HTTP request.  Without greet_pause it may make sendmail/SMTP server accent SMTP message especially to local mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks. This still seems so strange to me. I've never heard of a _HTTP_ proxy server connecting to a _SMTP_ server for anything and initiating cross-protocol conversation.

Comment: @MikeB This is by no means intended use of an HTTP proxy, this is someone having found an open HTTP proxy and abusing it to try to send email with requests like a HTTP POST to `http://foo.example.com:25/` and hoping that the SMTP server shrugs off the initial HTTP POST command and continues to process what is in the HTTP body (which could very well be valid SMTP commands).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Thanks for the example.  This makes more sense now.